# Odoo/OpenERP "Unable to login on database odoo"

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am trying to install Odoo on a hosted machine. First, I created a new Postgres user "odoo" with database "odoo". Then, I cloned the GIT repositry "https://github.com/odoo/odoo". After that I ran:

```
./openerp-server -s -c server.cfg
```

This created a configuration file named "server.cfg". I edited the configuration by changing the database parameters. After that, I ran

```
./openerp-server -c server.cfg
```

This loaded all the necessary addons and the server started running.

Whenever I open the browser, I keep getting to the following url:

```
http://erp.example.com/web/database/selector?error=Unable%20to%20login%20on%20database%20odoo
```

I thought maybe this is a database error. So, I checked the database and all the tables are created in the database.

The database user and password created all the tables but for some reason I can't login to the database.

Has anyone had an issue like this? If yes, how did you fix it?

Comment: How did you create the postgres role? It should be something like this `CREATE ROLE odoo WITH LOGIN REPLICATION PASSWORD 'odoo_password'`

Comment: Can you show us your `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: If this database is fresh then delete it. and try to create new Database

Comment: If it is not work. then show me the error in log file.

Comment: @BSLTechnologies The error log didn't show anything useful. It was only showing what requests were being made ([INFO] GET /web/database/selector - something in those lines).

Comment: @ChesuCR that's how I created the psql role/user. Sorry, not anymore. I ended up installing a precompiled odoo package for debian and it worked. But the pg_hba.conf didn't have anything special in it. I didn't touch anything besides database parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't set a password for your database yet, if it's the case: do it with this query :

```
ALTER USER odoo WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '<type your password here>';
```

or : run odoo in the debug mode for see some details about the problem : 
try this command

```
python openerp-server -r odoo -w '<the password>' --db_port=<5432 by default> --debug
```